# Delay after animating "scroll" to an element near the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I have a web page where I am showing a downward pointing arrow in a circle just above the fold to indicate that there is more content below.  When this arrow is clicked, I have jQuery in place to perform an animated scroll to the bottom of the page and then the jQuery scrolls back up to the desired place.  When the animation reaches the bottom of the page, I would like to have the jQuery immediately start scrolling upward to the desired place without having a brief pause while at the bottom of the page.  I tried using jQuery with and without using the function option at the end of each animate, and I am still noticing a pause when the first animate reaches the bottom of the page.

The sample page is located at:
[Click Here](http://seamlesstechnologygroup.com/minimal/)

My sample code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
         $("#arrow-circle").click(function (){
                //$(this).animate(function(){

                $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#footer-seamless-name").offset().top
                }, 2500);

                $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#arrow-circle").offset().top
                }, 1000);

                $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: getFoldHeight()
                }, 1000);
                //});
            });
       });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#arrow-circle").click(function (){
                //$(this).animate(function(){

                $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#footer-seamless-name").offset().top
                }, 2500, function() {

                    $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#arrow-circle").offset().top
                    }, 1000, function () {

                    $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: getFoldHeight()
                    }, 1000);
               //});
            });
        });
            });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Can include `html` ,`getFoldHeight()` at Question ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to consider the height of the window, because it scrolls to the top of the element. If your element is your footer that sticks to bottom, subtract window's height from the scroll position

Try this:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("body").height() - $(window).height() }, 2500,function() {
    $(this).animate({ scrollTop: $("#arrow-circle").offset().top }, 1000)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mag59hw7/11/

After it has finished scrolling to the end of document, it tries to scroll to your footer, which is located lower than the maximum amount you can scroll in the page. This is basically causing the delay

Comment: For purposes of learning, why does your approach happen without the undesired pause?

Comment: when you scroll to a particular position, your function scrolls to the top of element(in your case it's footer). You can't scroll to the top of the footer because it's lower that maximum scroll you can do in your page. That's why you need scroll to the `bottom of your document-window-height`. If your footer's height would be approximately your windows height it would work

Comment: Resize you browser window and make it equal to your footer height and YOUR CODE will work

Comment: Did my explanation help? @DaveD

Comment: Is this a correct understanding?  My initial approach was trying to scroll downward using an amount equal to the space between the top of the page and the footer element I had referenced.  Since the element to be clicked that starts this scroll process is located just above the initial fold, there isn't enough vertical height to scroll this amount, so the scroll reaches the end of the page before the the amount to be scrolled is depleted, so I was noticing a pause because the screen couldn't be scrolled downward any more yet the code was wanting to scroll some more.

Comment: Yes, window scroll position is 0 initially and it is the top of the page. When you want to scroll to footer you assume that when you finish scrolling footer will be on top of the page. As your footer is last element and it isn't high enough  to be on top, you can't scroll to the top of it. My solution is to scroll to the end of the page(bodHeight-windowHeight) and it will work whatever is your window height and footer height. I hope i could explain. It feels like I repeated myself in a couple of places. @DaveD